# Secret management through vault in docker containers

Tags: docker-compose, containers, dockerfile, hashicorp-vault

I am implementing vault for storing and accessing the secrets for my docker containers on other VM by installing vault in that docker container as well.

Is there any way that I could access secrets from my docker containers in another machine without installing hashicorp-vault on those containers.

Answer (score 3):

In order to access secrets from Vault you will need to authenticate, retrieve vault token and access the relevant secrets.

There are multiple authentication methods (user/pass, LDAP, JWT...). Read about it [here](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/) and decide which method fits your needs

Vault exposes rest api, which means that you don't need to install anything in order to access it. Just send the relevant http request.

For example - [here](https://www.vaultproject.io/api/secret/kv/kv-v2.html) is the `kv` http api (and an example - to list secrets)

```
$ curl \
    --header "X-Vault-Token: ..." \
    --request LIST \
    https://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/secret/metadata/my-secret
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple listeners in the vault configs.

```
listener "tcp" {
  address = "127.0.0.1:8200"
}

listener "tcp" {
  address = "<your_server_ip>:8200"
  tls_cert_file = path/to/certfile
  tls_key_file = path/to/keyfile
}
```

References 
https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/configuration/listener/tcp.html

Comment: Okay. If I add this then is there a need to login to vault inorder to access the secrets?

Comment: And if YES how can I login without installing VAULT

Comment: First, make sure Vault is unsealed. Second, use the REST API provided by Vault; Vault also provides the Client libraries.

Comment: So where do we store this token. Because if anyone got the access to that machine can take that token for fetching password. Then my application would be compromised.

Comment: You can enable other Auth methods, like LDAP or Okta etc.